# tikz explain/annotate equation in LaTeX using straight arrows with right angles

Tags: latex, tikz

Thanks to [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844/explain-formula-using-beamer), I can get an equation as in this figure: [with bent arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vslly.png). But what I really want is as in this figure: [with right-angled arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVCml.png).

To simply write the code, you may start by modifying the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844/explain-formula-using-beamer).

Comment: Can you post your source code? It'd be easier to work on this rather than rewriting everything from scratch.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I used [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844/explain-formula-using-beamer) . Mine is even worse since the location depends on my page \geometry settings QAQ.

Comment: You mean [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254858/141337) (you need to use the share link below each post)? Your figure looks a bit different, that's why I asked. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi, you are welcome to edit the file in [this link](https://cn.sharelatex.com/4975135844znbvfjhnbqhk) anytime.

Answer (score 3):

*Update:* I've turned equation annotation into a LaTeX [`annotate-equations` package](https://github.com/st--/annotate-equations) (also on CTAN), which you might find useful.

---

Adapting [Mike Renfro's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254858/171664)
to straight edges is fairly straightforward: all I did was change from

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->]<1-> (nCPP) edge [bend left] (tCPP);
        \path[->]<2-> (nL) edge [bend left] (tL);
        \path[->]<3-> (nPPP) edge [out=0, in=0] (tPPP);
        \path[->]<4-> (nPP) edge [out=0, in=-90] (tPP);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,->]
        \draw<1-> (nCPP) -| (tCPP);
        \draw<2-> (nL) -| (tL);
        \draw<3-> (nPPP) -| (tPPP);
        \draw<4-> (nPP) -| (tPP);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Changes explained:

- replaced the `edge` and `bend` options with `-|` (there's also `|-` to bend at right angles the other way)
- replaced `\path` with `\draw` to get the lines actually drawn
- moved `[->]` into the `tikzpicture` environment options because for some reason it didn't work as `\draw[->]`.

I've also set aspectratio=169 so there's enough space for the arrow for Predictor Prior Probability (it's also possible to work around that, but more hacky). This is what it looks like:

[image: example annotation with straight edges]